# Python 3 Syntax Error

Tags: python, python-3.x

```
  method = input("Is it currently raining? ")
if method=="Yes" :
  print("You should take the bus.")
else: distance = input("How far in km do you want to travel? ")
if distance == > 2:
    print("You should walk.")
elif distance ==  < 10 :
  print("You should take the bus.")
else: 
  print("You should ride your bike.")
```

Nvm, i fixed it..for those who have the same problem and were on Grok Learning it was just an indention issue and I forgot to write int...

Comment: Please don't change the code in your question after you've received answers.  It renders the answers meaningless.

Comment: @RichieHindle sorry I didn't know...I just needed to double check i copied the right code... :0 sorry

Comment: I've rolled this back to the code you have received answers for.

Comment: I answered his second question below (before you did that), so now you've rendered my answer meaningless :)

Comment: For the distance error, see the "also note that your code snippet" part of my second reply -- the "if distance" part will run for both branches of the first if statement, since it's not indented, but distance will only be assigned in the else branch.  You have to clean up the indentation so that things that belong together start in the same column.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So since you added a second question, I'll add a second answer :)

In Python 3, the `input()` function always returns a string, and you cannot compare strings and integers without converting things first (Python 2 had different semantics here).

```
>>> distance = input()
10
>>> distance
'10' <- note the quotes here
>>> distance < 10
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: unorderable types: str() < int()
```

To convert a string to an integer value, use `int(string)`:

```
>>> distance = int(distance)
>>> distance
10 <- no quotes here
>>> distance < 10
False
```

(also note that your code snippet above has an indentation issue -- you'll end up on the "if distance < 2" line whether you answer "Yes" or not.  To fix this, you have to indent everything that should be in the "else" branch in the same way.)

Answer (score 2):

You need to specify what to compare with for every comparison, so

```
elif distance <=2 and >=10
```

should be:

```
elif distance <=2 and distance >=10:
```

(there are more clever ways to do this, but the above is the quickest fix)

Comment: It's odd though 'cause logically that makes sense but it still shows an invalid syntax error! (Could it be due to wrong indention?)

Comment: @fredrik I have tried what you said and fixed the indention but it still shows wrong syntax (pointing at the 10 this time)...What have i done wrong? :/

Comment: @icktoofay What is COBOL??

Comment: @Joshua: A rather old programming language that is very likely irrelevant to you. Perhaps I shouldn't have mentioned it.

Comment: @icktoofay Oh ok if its anything above high school knowledge it's probably irrelevant :)

Comment: COBOL's is over 50 years old, but you'd be surprised to learn how many old programs that are still running (and being maintained by graybeards who still master ancient languages :-).  And yeah, while the language itself was very verbose, it did support the kind of abbreviation you made here -- you could leave out the left operand and even the operator if it was the same.  Python's less forgiving, though.

Comment: @Fredrik; not just graybeards.  We still run the occasional COBOL course for youngsters who have to maintain the stuff.  Included is instruction on how to remove cobwebs from GOTOs.  Now `pass`: a bit like `NEXT SENTENCE`, don't you think?